# Value not getting set in page scope in struts2

Tags: struts2, ognl

While using this -

```
<s:set var="sample" value="%{'start'}" scope="page"/>
```

When I print the value of var sample using

```
<s:property value="#page.sample"/>
```

I do not get anything. When I use the scope=request then I get the value. Why is value not getting set in page scope?

Answer (score 3):

To access 'page' scope variables you have to use the following:

```
<s:property value="#attr.sample" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Because JSP will be translated into servlets, variables with page scope are local varialbes of generated service() method of servlet, once service() method terminates, the page scoped variables will be recycled.

more easiely to say, JSP does have page scope, but servlet does not.